# How to get dependencyClasspath in sbt build without triggering compilation?

Tags: scala, sbt

In sbt `show dependencyClasspath` triggers compilation. Actually, it is the `internalDependencyClasspath` which does that. I was wondering if I can get the classpath of the inter-project dependencies for both `Test` and `Compile` scope without triggering compilation?

Comment: you may try this [sbt-plugin](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph)

Comment: that unfortunately only gives the information about dependencies (groupId, artificatId, version) but not about the classpath

Comment: If you downvote a question, please share why do you think it is a bad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a dirty little hack: temporarily remove all source files from project structure so that there's nothing to actually compile but target directories and project dependencies remain the same:

```
set every sources := Seq.empty
show dependencyClasspath
```

Comment: Is there a way how to do this in a plugin?

Comment: Actually, yes, this can be run from a plugin. Thanks!

Comment: @fikovnik Actually, how?

Comment: For example: `commands += Command.command("metadata") { state => "set every sources := Seq.empty" :: "show dependencyClasspath" :: state }`